# Extract a single word from a text block

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to use powershell to recover a hostname from a text block. The block goes as follows:

```
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.
Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  svc.sXXX.d.fdb
Source Workstation: DIXXXEF01
Error Code: 0x0
```

As you can see its a multi-line text block. Currently I'm trying to cut down on the fluff of some 5 gigs of security logs. I was hoping to use a powershell regrex command or something similar to recover just the Logon Account and Source Workstation.

Any ideas? Thanks.

ISJ

Comment: Try this:
$account = 'Logon Account:'
$workstation = 'Source Workstation:'
$textBlock | Where-Object { $_ -like "$account*" -or $_ -like "$workstation*" } | Foreach-Object 
{ 
  IF ($_ -like "$account*") {$_.Trim($account)};
  IF ($_ -like "$workstation*") {$_Trim($workstation)}
}
Not sure it's gonna work due to the size (5GB), might need to use Stream or something and I've got no experience of that in Powershell I'm afraid. If it works it will look like this though:
svc.sXXX.d.fdb
DIXXXEF01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Content` and `Select-String`:

```
get-content logfile.txt | select-string '^Logon Account|^Source workstation'
```

The `^` character means 'start of line'. See the PowerShell help topic `about_Regular_Expressions` for more information.

Comment: Can you really handle that amount of data with get-content though? I've experienced that if you can't open it in notepad (which you can't), you can't use get-content. I'm thinking he might need to use Streamreader or something. But I guess he can alteast try :) And if it doesn't work he can modify it to work with Streamreader or w/e would work.

Comment: You can use the `-ReadCount` parameter to alter `Get-Content`'s buffer size. This can make a significant difference for large input.

Comment: I tried this ( $feResult.Message -replace "\n" | Select-String -Pattern 'Account:.\w' ) but it still just returns the entire string and not the word following "Account:".

Comment: What is `$feResult.Message`? You don't mention it in your original question.

Comment: You don't need get-content at all. Just use the -Path parameter of Select-String. That said Get-Content with -ReadCount and -Match will be faster than select-string.

Comment: Sorry thats the block of text I'm drawing from. Its quoted in code in the original message.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I actually ended up splitting all the lines by the new line character then searching for the string using Select-String to pull that line. From there I replaced out the test on that line that was not related to the account or hostname. 

Its not the ideal solution but it worked.

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

Using Get-Content with -ReadCount and -match and borrowing Bill's regex):

```
Get-Content $file -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach { $_ -match '^Logon Account|^Source workstation' } |
 Add-Content $newfile
```

You can tune that by changing the -ReadCount parameter.  Typically counts of 1000-5000 produce the best results.

You can also use Select-String, but it returns MatchInfo objects which contain a lot of other data you don't need for this application. It's great if you do need it, but it takes about 4x as long to apply the same regex with Select-String as it does with -match, and if all you needed out of it is the strings, Select-String is overkill. (IMHO)